# What xpath query would solve this

Tags: ruby, xpath, html-parsing, nokogiri, mechanize

What XPath query could I use to solve the below.  I'm actually using nokogiri (in ruby) so ideally the answer would be in the form of a ruby nokogiri form, but else just XPath and I can adapt in.

#### Required Output

I'm seeking to parse the below HTML (a full html page, but I've just copy/pasted the relevant part for clarity), and end up with basically the following:

```
Phone Number   Plan ID
545454545      12345
3434343434     67890
```

So in the context of Ruby/nokogiri this could be in a Hash for example:

```
% result = { "545454545" => "12345",  "3434343434" => "67890" }
```

#### HTML to be Parsed

```
.
.
.
<form method="post">
   <div style='line-height:18px;background-color:#FFFFFF;border: 1px #dedede solid;padding:10px;'>
   <table width='90%' border=0>
      <tr>
         <td width='30%'> Plan ID </td>
         <td width='70%'> 12345 </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td> Phone Number </td>
         <td> 545454545 </td>
      </tr>
      .
      .
      .
      </table>
   </div>
   <br>
   .
   .
   .
   <div style='line-height:18px;background-color:#FFFFFF;border: 1px #dedede solid;padding:10px;'>
   <table width='90%' border=0>
      <tr>
         <td width='30%'> Plan ID </td>
         <td width='70%'> 67890 </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td> Phone Number </td>
         <td> 3434343434 </td>
      </tr>
      .
      .
      .
      </table>
   </div>
   <br>
```

Comment: The dot lines which you've removed, do they contain more results you want to collect or is that complete redundant data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming those lines you've replaced with periods do not contain data you want to collection, which would mean each table provided a unique result set, the following would work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri.HTML DATA.read
results = {}

doc.search('table').each do |table|
  plan_id = table.at('tr[1]/td[2]')
  phone_number = table.at('tr[2]/td[2]')

  if plan_id && phone_number
    results[phone_number.text.strip] = plan_id.text.strip
  end
end

p results #=> {"545454545"=>"12345", "3434343434"=>"67890"}

__END__
<form method="post">
   <div style='line-height:18px;background-color:#FFFFFF;border: 1px #dedede solid;padding:10px;'>
   <table width='90%' border=0>
      <tr>
         <td width='30%'> Plan ID </td>
         <td width='70%'> 12345 </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td> Phone Number </td>
         <td> 545454545 </td>
      </tr>
      .
      .
      .
      </table>
   </div>
   <br>
   .
   .
   .
   <div style='line-height:18px;background-color:#FFFFFF;border: 1px #dedede solid;padding:10px;'>
   <table width='90%' border=0>
      <tr>
         <td width='30%'> Plan ID </td>
         <td width='70%'> 67890 </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td> Phone Number </td>
         <td> 3434343434 </td>
      </tr>
      .
      .
      .
      </table>
   </div>
   <br>
```

Comment: thanks heaps for responding - actually I mean the periods to mean there can be other elements in between sorry. Do you mind if I ask what changes would it take so (a) limit the table search to only items within the the 1st FORM on the page, (b) for each Table found search all children to find the "Plan ID" child and "Phone Number" child.  thanks again

Comment: oh, actually ignore my part (b) question - it seems the rows I need are always the 1st and 2nd in the able - so it's just part (a).

Comment: I only see ONE form in your example. You should provide a more relevant example snippet. But you can simply do `search(form/table)` assuming the form has an action or class/id you can use that CSS selector to specifically select that form, ie: `search('form[id="some_form"]/table')`

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
xpath = '//td[contains(text(),"Phone Number") or contains(text(),"Plan ID")]/following-sibling::td'
Hash[*doc.xpath(xpath).map{|x| x.text.strip}.reverse]
```